# How to convert single element list to java 8 optional

Tags: java, collections, java-8, option-type

How to nicely convert list containing one or zero elements to Optional?

The ugly code:

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

Optional<Integer> optional = integers.size() == 0 ?
        Optional.empty() :
        Optional.of(integers.get(0));
```

Comment: With Java 8, you don’t need the explicit type arguments anymore: `List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();` and `Optional<Integer> optional = ints.isEmpty()? Optional.empty(): Optional.ofNullable(ints.get(0));`

Comment: Thx, I have wrong language level :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [`Stream#findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) method, which:

> Returns an Optional describing the first element of this stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty.

```
List<Integer> list = ...
Optional<Integer> optional = list.stream().findFirst();
```

Alternatively, with the same success you can also use the [`Stream#findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) method.

Comment: Note that slight semantic difference: the question’s code uses `ofNullable` which implies that an empty `Optional` is returned if the list is non-empty but contains a `null` at the first place. In contrast `Stream.findFirst()` will throw an exception if an element is present, but `null`.