# How to convert a List to List<Optional>?

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

How can I convert a `List` to `List<Optional>`?

The following code produces a compilation error :

```
public Collection<Optional<UserMeal>> getAll() {

    Comparator comparator = new SortedByDate();
    List<UserMeal> mealList = new ArrayList<>(repository.values());
    Collections.sort(mealList,comparator);
    Collections.reverse(mealList);

    **List<Optional<UserMeal>> resultList = Optional.of(mealList);**

    return resultList;
}
```

Comment: Consider having a look at for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868069/how-to-convert-single-element-list-to-java-8-optional

Comment: Your question and your code are asking 2 different things. Your title and body says you want a `Optional<List>` but your code uses a `List<Optional<UserMeal>>`, which is it?

Comment: General code review comments: 1) don't use a raw `Comparator`. You probably want `Comparator<UserMeal>`. 2) Instead of sorting and reversing, just reverse the comparator using `Comparator.reversed()`. 3) It's rather odd to have a `List<Optional<T>>`. What does it mean to have an empty Optional in the midst of a list? Since the list has been sorted, it's no longer correlated by index to any other data structure. Maybe some rethinking of the object modeling is required here.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want `Optional<List<T>>`, then it's usually preferable simply to have an empty list instead of an optional list. For instance, you can loop or stream over empty vs non-empty lists unconditionally without having to unpack the Optional, etc.

Comment: You should really think hard whether you want to return something like Collection<Optional<T>>. If the intention was to allow null values in the collection, I would really consider to filter them out before returning the collection.

Comment: Why exactly would you **not** want to return a Collection<Optional<T>> ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Optional.of(mealList)` returns an `Optional<List<UserMeal>>`, not a `List<Optional<UserMeal>>`.

To get the desired `List<Optional<UserMeal>>`, you should wrap each element of the `List` with an `Optional` :

```
List<Optional<UserMeal>> resultList = 
    mealList.stream()
            .map(Optional::ofNullable)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note I used `Optional::ofNullable` and not `Optional::of`, since the latter would produce a `NullPointerException` if your input `List` contains any null elements.

Comment: Why would you not want a `NullPointerException` if your list contained null elements?

Comment: @Louis Wasserman: why would you want a `List<Optional>` if you sort out `null` elements via exception? Not that using something like `List<Optional>` was a recommended coding style…

Answer (score 4):

Simple conversion of mealList to Optional

Optional.ofNullable(mealList)